# Used jsondecode to get mult-dimensional array, how do I access all children elements

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array, screen-scraping

So I used JSON to obtain a multidimensional array. What I'm trying to do is for each listing in the main part of the array (not sure what the technical term is) access the part of the array that is below. I would then like to echo each one of these links.

As you can probably see I'm trying to scrape the images. How do I go about doing this? I love to learn so some hints at first would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

```
[url] => http://imgur.com/0q4G4qP
```

**Json code**

```
<?php

$jsonurl = "http://www.reddit.com/r/pics.json";
$data    = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$array   = json_decode($data, true);

echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

I am not entirely sure how to do this. I referenced the php manual on how to access these types of arrays, but I'm a bit lost. Basically for everyone of those children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
foreach ($multi_d_array['data']['children'] as $item) {
    echo $item['data']['url'].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Wow. I am actually trying to build someone else's image scraper from scratch to learn. This is so much more incredibly simple. The previous program used regex to search for all listings of .jgp etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) in loops `foreach($data as $d) { echo $d['url'] ;}`